# Dynamically add QGraphicsEllipseItems

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

Basically, each time I click on a graphicsview, I'd like a new QGraphicsEllipseItem to appear. The number is up to the user. Also, I'd like to query all of them in the end with pos() to get all their positions. The number of ellipses is not known before hand and their positions are movable by the ItemIsMovable flag. Anyone know how could I do this?

I could make an array of pointers to the graphicsitem class but that would possibly waste memory and limit the number of ellipses I can make. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as much items as you want to the scene (as long as there is free memory space, of course):

```
myGraphicsScene->addEllipse(rect, pen, brush);
```

In order to add items for each click, reimplement the `mousePressEvent` of the `QGraphicsView`:

```
void MyGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    int rx = 10; // radius of the ellipse
    int ry = 20;
    QRect rect(e->x() - rx, e->y() - ry, 2*rx, 2*ry);
    scene()->addEllipse(rect, pen, brush);

    // call the mousePressEvent of the super class:
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(e);
}
```

You don't have to store the pointers by yourself. When you want to query some piece of information of all items in the scene, just loop over the list of items provided by the scene:

```
foreach(QGraphicsItem *item, myGraphicsScene->items())
    qDebug() << "Item geometry =" << item->boundingRect();
```

(or for the position only: `item->pos()`)

If you want to query a piece of information of a subclass of `QGraphicsItem`, you can cast the item to your type using Qt's QGraphicsItem casting mechanism, which returns a null pointer if the item isn't of the requested type. After checking the pointer to be not null, you can access your own member:

```
foreach(QGraphicsItem *item, myGraphicsScene->items())
{
    MyDerivedItem *derivedItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<MyDerivedItem*>(item);
    if(derivedItem) // check success of QGraphicsItem cast
        qDebug() << derivedItem->yourCustomMethod();
}
```

Comment: Leemes, Thanks again. Is there a way I can use foreach for a subclass of QGraphicsItem and then ask it for a member I added to the class? As in:
    foreach(Deriveditem *item, myGraphicsSecne->items())
    qDebug() << "Item property =" << item->member();

Comment: Of course you can ;) See my updated answer. I hope this is what you asked for. Always remember to use the safe qobject_cast *and check the result* before using it. This extends to every cast of QObjects.

Comment: That last example won't compile. `qobject_cast` takes a QObject*, but QGraphicsItem does not inherit from QObject. You want `qgraphicsitem_cast`.

Comment: Leemes thanks again for the response. I can't get it to work quite right. The class in question is actually derived from QGraphicsEllipseItem. I attempted to cast it but the compiler complained "no matching function for call to ‘qobject_cast(QGraphicsItem*&)’." I tried replacing qobject_cast with qgraphicsitem_cast but the compiler said the class graphicsitem doesnt have the memeber im trying to access.

Comment: Oops. Implemented it incorrectly. The above code works with qgraphicsitem_cast replaced. Thanks again leemes.

Comment: Oh, my fault. QGraphicsItems aren't QObjects. Sorry ;)